# MySql Outer Join Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I am having an error trying to outer join 4 tables, 2 x 2, to match the missing links between both I want to show also those rows without match.

This query works fine:

```
select
  r.name    AS r,
  a.name    AS a,
  f.name    AS f
from Field f
     join Order o 
    on f.f2o = o.oid
     join Resource r 
    on r.name = o.name
     join Attribute a 
    on a.a2r= r.oid and f.name = a.name;
```

But if I use left or outer, it no longer works. This does not work:

```
select
  r.name    AS r,
  a.name    AS a,
  f.name    AS f
from Field f
     join Order o 
    on f.f2o = o.oid
     join Resource r 
    on r.name = o.name
     outer join Attribute a             -- <--- here is the issue
    on a.a2r= r.oid and f.name = a.name;
```

Returning

> 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings
>
> Query: select r.name AS r, a.name AS a, f.name AS f, oi.action AS
>   action from t_m_prod_action_oitem_fld f join t_m_prod_action_oitem
>   oi...
>
> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'outer join t_m_attr a     on a.attr2rfs = r.oid and
>   f.name = a.name LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 11

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing. Either use a `LEFT JOIN`, a `RIGHT JOIN` or emulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` using the union of the `LEFT JOIN` *and* `RIGHT JOIN`.

JOINs are very different across different SQL dialects. Some call the joins slightly different, some don't have specific joins, some support them using a different syntax (such as not having `CROSS JOIN` but you can still do a `CROSS JOIN` using `JOIN` without an `ON` condition). Always read the docs of the SQL dialect you're using.

Some people use `outer join` to mean `full outer join` where as other people use `outer join` as a category that has the three `left`, `right` and `full` `outer` joins. But MySQL doesn't have a `full outer join`.